# How is it possible to call URI module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I design a module which will behave similar to URI module? I mean something like this:

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > require 'uri'
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > URI.class
 => Module 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > URI("http://google.com")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x0000010d8f6bd8 URL:http://google.com>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to have a method and a class/module with the same name:

```
1.8.7 > class Foo; end
 => nil 
1.8.7 > def Foo; 42; end
 => nil 
1.8.7 > Foo
 => Foo 
1.8.7 > Foo()
 => 42
```